# Return inside of recursive function doesn't 'work' if short if is used

Tags: java, recursion

I have this odd issue I can't explain to myself, when using **short if** inside of return. This code (see below) should return the value 55 but instead it just returns the argument 10 which I passed to it by value.

I already debugged the function and the recursion works as intended but it never adds the `+ 1` to the return value.

```
public static int add(int i) {
    return i == 0 ? 0 : add(i - 1) + 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(add(10)); // returns 10
}
```

How come this doesn't work?

Comment: Seems you are subtracting 1 from `i` before adding 1 , with `(i - 1) + 1`

Comment: The sum of numbers `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n` is equal to `n(n + 1) / 2`. Calculating this would be far faster.

Comment: @Obicere but then it wouldn't be an exercise in recursion :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yep. Past few times people have posted it, they have actually been attempting to compute that value. Also a good thing to know.

Comment: 1+1+1... = 10.
Are you trying to do i+(i-1)+(i-2)...? Then replace +1 with +i

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code does what you're telling it to. At each recursion step it reduces one from the counter and adds 1 to the result - since it's counting `i` times, it'll return `i`.

What you're trying to do is *sum* the numbers from `0` to `i`. In order to do this you need to add `i` and not `1` to the sum each time.

```
public static int add(int i) {
    return i == 0 ? 0 : add(i - 1) + i; // <- like this
}
```

Since this is likely an exercise, consider implementing factorial recursively to make sure you understand the concept (that is, a function that takes `n` and returns `n * (n-1) * (n-2) ...` and so on.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was about to check, whether I could _shortify_ the code I already had and made a mistake while converting it.